# linqToTwitter and Windows Phone projects

Tags: linq, windows-phone-7, c#-4.0

I created a new Windows Phone application and added the linqToTwitter package. This added a reference to LinqToTwitterAg but I cannot start using TwitterContext or anything like that and cannot add 'using LinqToTwitterAg' or 'using LinqToTwitter'. Does LinqToTwitter not play well with Windows Phone applications?

Answer (score 1):

When I tried to install the LinqToTwitter package via NuGet, I got the following error:

> Successfully installed 'LinqToTwitter 2.0.21'. 
>   Successfully uninstalled 'LinqToTwitter 2.0.21'.  
>   Install failed. Rolling back... 
>   Could not install package 'LinqToTwitter 2.0.21'.  
>   You are trying to install this package into a project that targets 
>   Silverlight,Version=v4.0,Profile=WindowsPhone71', but the package
>   does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that
>   framework. For more information, contact the package author.

My suggestion would be to reach out to the package author and see if he can create a pacakge for you that is compatible with the Windows Phone 7.1 framework, or get the source yourself and try compliing it into your solution.